# Alert box displaying 'undefined' instead of success message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm building a server-side rendered website with Node. I want to display a green alert box upon successfully updating data in updateSettings.js. Even though the user data (name and email) is updated on Compass correctly, I get a red alert box (error) with undefined as the message. In the browser console, I get a 'bad request' error from bundle.js.
Also, no code seems to run after the Axios PATCH request code

**updateSettings.js**

```
/* eslint-disable */
import axios from 'axios';
import { showAlert } from './alerts';

export const updateData = async (name, email) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: 'PATCH',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/users/updateMe',
      data: {
        name,
        email,
      },
    });

    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
    showAlert('success', 'Data updated successfully!');
    }

  } catch (err) {
    showAlert('error', err.response.data.message);
  }
};
```

**Alerts.js**

```
/* eslint-disable */

export const hideAlert = () => {
  const el = document.querySelector('.alert');
  if (el) el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
};

// type is 'success' or 'error'
export const showAlert = (type, msg) => {
  hideAlert();
  const markup = `<div class="alert alert--${type}">${msg}</div>`;
  document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup);
  window.setTimeout(hideAlert, 5000);
};
```

**Index.js**
`

```
/* eslint-disable */
import '@babel/polyfill';
import { login, logout } from './login';
import { displayMap } from './leaflet';
import { updateData } from './updateSettings';

// DOM ELEMENTS
const leaflet = document.getElementById('map');
const loginForm = document.querySelector('.form--login');
const logOutBtn = document.querySelector('.nav__el--logout');
const updateDataForm = document.querySelector('.form-user-data');

// DELEGATION
if (leaflet) {
  const locations = JSON.parse(leaflet.dataset.locations);
  displayMap(locations);
}

if (loginForm)
  loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    login(email, password);
  });

if (logOutBtn) logOutBtn.addEventListener('click', logout);

if (updateDataForm)
  updateDataForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    updateData(name, email);
  });
```

`

Running the node debugger indicates that process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined but I'm using dotenv for this so it should be working just fine. In any case, the login functionality which is quite similar and uses axios runs just fine.

**App.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const hpp = require('hpp');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

// eslint-disable-next-line node/no-deprecated-api
const exp = require('constants');
const AppError = require('./utilities/appError');
const globalErrorHandler = require('./controllers/errrorController');

const tourRouter = require('./routes/tourRoutes');
const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const reviewRouter = require('./routes/reviewRoutes');
const viewRouter = require('./routes/viewRoutes');

const app = express(); //express is a function which upon calling will add a bunch of methods to the app variable

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// 1.GLOBAL MIDDLEWARES
// Serving static files
// app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Set Security HTTP headers
app.use(helmet());

// Development logging
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // the readinng of the process only needs to happen once, and the process is the same no matter which file we're in
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

// Limit requests from same API
const limiter = rateLimit({
  max: 100,
  windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
  message: 'Too many requests from this IP, please try again in an hour',
});

app.use('/api', limiter);

// Body parser: reading data from body into req.body
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' })); //'express.json' here is middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '10kb' }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Data sanitization against NoSQL query injection
app.use(mongoSanitize());

// Data sanitization agains XSS
app.use(xss());

// Prevent parameter pollution
app.use(
  hpp({
    whitelist: [
      'duration',
      'ratingsAverage',
      'ratingsQuantity',
      'maxGroupSize',
      'difficulty',
      'price',
    ],
  })
);

// Test middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // we have access to the requestTime property; assuming we want to display the time of the request
  req.requestTime = new Date().toISOString();
  next();
  console.log(req.cookies);
});

// 3. ROUTES: this is where we mount our routers

// these 3 routers are actually middlewares that we mount upon the paths
app.use('/', viewRouter); //mounted right on the root URL
app.use('/api/v1/tours', tourRouter); //we've created a sub-app with this
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/reviews', reviewRouter);
// this router is essentially a sub-app for each resource
// the request goes into middleware and when it hits the above line of code, it will match the url, and thus the tourRouter middleware function will run

app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {
  next(new AppError(`Cant find ${req.originalUrl} on this server!`, 404));
});

app.use(globalErrorHandler);

module.exports = app;
```

**/updateMe**

```
exports.updateMe = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  // 1) Create error if user POSTs password data
  if (req.body.password || req.body.passwordConfirm) {
    return next(
      new AppError(
        'This route is not for password updates. Please use /updateMyPassword',
        400
      )
    );
  }

  // 2) Filter out unwanted field names that are not allowed to be updated
  const filteredBody = filterObj(req.body, 'name', 'email');

  // 3) Update user document
  const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, filteredBody, {
    new: true,
    runValidators: true,
  });

  res.status(400).json({
    status: 'success',
    data: {
      user: updatedUser,
    },
  });
});
```

**package.json**

```
    "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
    "debugger": "ndb server.js",
    "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js",
    "build:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "Dave Odipo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "b": "^2.0.1",
    "babel": "file:../../../../../../../../polyfill",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-mongo-sanitize": "^2.2.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^6.6.0",
    "helmet": "3.16",
    "hpp": "^0.2.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.15",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.8.0",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "slugify": "^1.6.5",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "xss-clean": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "win-node-env": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0"
  }
}
```

Please help

Comment: I read you got dotenv but seems there is no dotenv at `App.js`. If the error occurs because `dotenv` isn't imported, then the problem is defined and can be solved with ease.

Comment: Can you post the code where you declare the `/updateMe` route in express?

Comment: It's not a completed answer but you may check if there is `process.env.NODE_ENV` by `console.log(process.env)`.

Comment: try changing `res.status(400).json({`  => `res.status(200).json({`

Comment: Thanks mate @traynor all I needed to do was change `res.status(400).json({` to `res.status(200).json({`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `res.status(400).json({` to `res.status(200).json({`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).